# Java_home No such file or directory in Linux terminal

Tags: bash, kubuntu

Hello I have a problem my linux terminal shows bash: java_home: No such file or directory, when I type echo $JAVA_HOME I get /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64 and echo $PATH shows /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/bin:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games. When I write a sudo apt-get install I get JAVA_HOME:not find I can't find a problem, I'm using kubuntu, below you can see my terminal and and my .profile file in my home directory. Maybe someone knows how to fix it. Thank you in advance.

[image]

[image]

Comment: please post text as text. It is easier to read that way (especially for blind people).

Comment: The indexable text here does not even match what the computer said.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The crucial error message is:

```
/usr/sbin/update-info-dir: 2: /etc/environment: JAVA_HOME: not found
```

This indicates the error message is coming from `/usr/sbin/update-info-dir`, which is a script that can be executed as part of package install/remove operations. It is reading (sourcing) the `/etc/environment` file and encountering an error in there.

`/etc/environment` is supposed to contain POSIX-shell-style environment variable assignments only, i.e.

```
VARIABLE_NAME=value
```

It is essential to have **no spaces before or after the equals sign**: if there are spaces, the variable name will be interpreted as a shell command and the shell will attempt to execute it.

I'm guessing that your `/etc/environment` file probably contains something like

```
JAVA_HOME = /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64
```

so instead of assigning the pathname to environment variable `$JAVA_HOME`, the shell reading the file will interpret it as a shell command to be executed. It will attempt to execute a command named literally `JAVA_HOME` with two parameters, `=` and `/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64`. Since a command named `JAVA_HOME` does not exist, that will result in an error message.

Edit your `/etc/environment` file and remove any spaces before/after the equal sign in environment variable assignments.

Comment: Thank you now I can use sudo apt-get install, but error in the top left corner bash: java_home: No such file or directory is still there.

Comment: Is it really "java_home" in all lower case? Then you might try `grep -r java_home /etc`: it will find every location under `/etc` (the system-wide configuration directory) where that exact string appears. You might also search for it in your per-user login/shell startup scripts with: `grep java_home ~/.profile ~/.bash*` (note: any files with a dot as the first character of the filename are normally hidden; you'll need the `ls -a` command to see them).

Answer (score 0):

sudo does not maintain your environment variables. Try

```
sudo JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64 apt-get ...
```

If this isn't allow by your sudo config, try `sudo -i` followed by `JAVA_HOME=... apt-get...` as above